# Community bot posts additional bounty

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just saw something for the first time where the user [Community](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) posted an additional bounty on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you). As it turns out, this user (Community) is a bot. I thought this was amusing, but I'm also curious how is a background process empowered to do this? What criteria must be met by an answer to trigger the bot to do post a bounty? How big can these bounties be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Information systems that associate an owner with all objects in them need to account for what happens to those objects when their original owners go the way of all things.

What happened in this specific case is that someone posted a bounty and then self-deleted their own account.

Whenever that happens, the orphaned bounty is adopted by, or if you would, “re-owned” by the Community user (`user id == −1`).

This is like how when the parent process exits while it still has running children, those orphaned child processes are adopted by *init* (`process id == 1`), so that there are never any unowned processes.

It remains an open question whether the moderation team or the SE team will be manually awarding those bounties before they expire, or whether the default 50% unawarding process will be followed.  My bet is on the latter, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That does not explain why a bounty was posted on that question, 3 years after it was posted and answered?

Comment: @oerkelens That is something you would have to ask of the self-deleted user, who is no longer with us.

Comment: @tchrist did you mean to use a commonly-used euphemism for "dead" in that comment?

Comment: Hello! It seems that you have refunded the *wong* bounty. Please see chat, and "take the biscuit" question.